# Java / Spring: "Tagging" beans in XML to get specific bean by class and tag

Tags: java, spring

I have big XML config made from several files.

I need to get bean implementing specific interface. But there are several implementations so I have to choose. I want to tag bean with special "tag" to get it easily:

```
<bean class="myInterfaceImpl1" tag="beanForMe" />
<bean class="myInterfaceImpl2" />
<bean class="myInterfaceImpl3" />

T get(Class<T> clazz) {
    return factory.getBean(clazz, "beanForMe"); //Returns first one 
}
```

Does there is something like that in spring?

I found 2 workaround. First is to use special tag id:

**first**

```
<bean class="myInterfaceImpl1" id="MyInterface-beanForMe" />
```

But when I rename class in My IDE everything would fail unless I write IDE plugin to support my idea.

**Second** is to add all "tagged" beans to specific list, get it by id and then iterate through it to find appropriate bean.

But tags would be the best here. What do you think?

Comment: What's the point of the tag? How is it any better than specifying an ID or name?

Comment: Java code accepts class name as argument and should find appropriate bean. In that case id has to be derivative from class name. See my "first" idea and why do not I like it

Comment: That seems kind of backwards, seems like you're adding an unnecessary layer of abstraction to a framework that already provides it, but  your usecase isn't clear to me--I'm likely missing something.

Comment: Our ORM needs to create instance of specific class and fill it with data from database. But this class also requires injection of certain services. Services do exist in spring context as beans. ORM goes to spring context and looks for appropriate bean (with scope "prototype") to create new object. ORM knows only class but there are several beans in context with the same class. I want to have tag like "this-bean-is-for-orm" so ORM would be able to find all beans by class and then look for bean with specific tag. I can use id (like "com.example.MyClass-for-orm") but renaming class would fail

Answer (score 5):

Spring has a notion of [qualifiers](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) for exactly that purpose:

```
<bean class="myInterfaceImpl1">
    <qualifier value = "beanForMe" />
</bean>
```

Unfortunately, they are intended to be used only for autowiring, but you can access them manually, though it would be quite ugly:

```
ConfigurableListableBeanFactory cbf = ((ConfigurableListableBeanFactory) factory);
BeanDefinition bd = cbf.getBeanDefinition(name);
AutowireCandidateQualifier q = ((AbstractBeanDefinition) bd).getQualifier(Qualifier.class.getName());
String value = (String) q.getAttribute(AutowireCandidateQualifier.VALUE_KEY);
```

Comment: Thank you. Too bad they do not have streamlined interface for that. I do not want to use autowire here. I asked them to support new interface: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8891 let's see if SpringSource would do something